# Configuring apache httpd.conf file with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, apache

As per one of the tutorial on configuring phpMyAdmin I configured the apache/conf/httpd.conf file as follows to establish the connection for PHP in apache.

```
PHPIniDir "c:\webserver\php"
LoadModule php5_module "c:\webserver\php\php5apache2_4.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
```

I am getting an error:

```
The request operation has failed
```

While restarting apache with the above changes. Where am I going wrong? Please can somebody explain how to figure it out.

Comment: Use forward slashes `/` instead of `\\` in path names. Apache works with forward slash in windows also. also please mention the version of PHP and Apache you are using.

Comment: Try `httpd -k start` from the Apache/bin folder and see what error message you are getting.

Comment: @Bansi Thank you for the reply. I tried with \ but still apache is not getting started. The apache and PHP versions are httpd-2.2.25-win32-x86-no_ssl and php-5.5.6-Win32-VC11-x86 respectively. Also, I tried using httpd -k start but it says                       **httpd: Syntax error on line 133 of C:/webserver/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot l
oad C:/webserver/php/php5apache2_4.dll into server: The specified module could not be found. **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With httpd-2.2.25 you should be using `php5apache2_2.dll` not `php5apache2_4.dll`.

Change the line

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:\webserver\php\php5apache2_4.dll"
```

to

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/webserver/php/php5apache2_2.dll"
```

Comment: I downloaded another version of PHP. Thank you. It works fine now.